# Flex - JavaScript works on bin-debug, but not on deployed server

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

My Flex application is successfully calling functions in a JavaScript file through the ExternalInterface class when these are in the bin-debug folder and the JS file is located in the same directory as the Flex app.

But when I test the Flex app on the server, it is not interacting with the JavaScript. The only difference I can find is that on the remote server the JS file is being pulled in from a URL, instead of locally. The JS file URL is in the same domain as the Flex application, therefore I don't think this is a cross-domain issue. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the URL. This requires an additional security setting in your ActionScript code.

You need to include the following in your ActionScript code:

```
Security.allowDomain("mysite.com")
```

Here is a graphic description from Adobe:

[alt text http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/images/crossScript_load.png](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/images/crossScript_load.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `allowScriptAccess` parameter in the SWF embedding html is not set to `never`. If it is currently set to `never`, change it to `sameDomain` or `always`.